# Shell script does not find file with space in name

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I created two scripts to make a checksum of a lot of files, in one of them I use the 'find' command to search the files in a specific directory, but when the file has a name with space character, `file one.txt` for example, the script takes this as two files: `file` and `one`. I know that error is in the 'find' command line, but I don't know what I do wrong.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find $1 -type f -exec bash ./task2.sh "{}" \;
```

Comment: do `find "$1" -type f -exec bash ...`

Comment: I tried it,but the output is: "find: cannot search `': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

In order to search for a file with spaces in the name you either have to enclose the argument in quotes or escape the spaces. Like:

`find "test file.txt"` or alternatively `find test\ file.txt`.

The easiest fix in your particular use case is to enclose `$1` in quotes:

`find "$1" -type f -exec bash ./task2.sh "{}" \;`

Comment: I did it but did not work..the output now is: "find: cannot search `': No such file or directory"

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva try echo-ing the contents of `$1`. This error is not related to the name containing spaces.

Comment: the variable $1 receive a parameter, in this case, i set the path of directory that I wish to run the checksums or move the bash file to the directory specific and just run this without any parameter, that is what I do, so he takes automatically the path where he are...